# SequenceEqual for specific properties

Tags: c#

I would like to compare two lists of objects. The objects have four different properties. I need to compare only three of them as sequence (only three because one is always different).

An example would be as follows:

```
list1 = new List<myClass>() { new myClass(10, "a", 100, "unique1"),
    new myClass(10, "a", 100, "unique2") };

list2 = new List<myClass>() { new myClass(10, "a", 100, "unique3"),
    new myClass(10, "a", 100, "unique4") };
```

Can I compare those lists as sequence without the fourth (unique) property? Desired result for the exapmle would be TRUE.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) overload that allows you to pass in an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation that only includes the properties that you wish to compare.

The example on that [linked page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) overload that allows you to specify a custom `IEqualityComparer` - implement a custom one that only compares the three properties you are interested in.